# Creating object from parent class and call class from child class

Tags: php, oop

I have one class created but is huge and has to many methodes. I want to slice to separate child classes.

I attempt something like this:

---

```
class ParentClass{

}

class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{

      public function childFunction1(){

      }

}

class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass{

      public function childFunction2(){

      }

}

$myObject = new ParentClass();
$myObject->childFunction1();
$myObject->childFunction2();
```

---

But not working.
It's that possible? 
Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: parent Class cannot access child methods but child can

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not work that way.  What you're doing is instantiating an empty class and trying to call methods on it.

You should use [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) instead.  The basic idea is to `compose` multiple objects into your main object.  Break off objects by their functionality.  Always remember to follow the [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) and the rest of SOLID.

Answer (score 0):

```
class ParentClass {

}


class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{

    public function childFunction1(){

    }

}

class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass{

    public function childFunction2(){

    }

}

$myObject1 = new ChildClass1();
$myObject2 = new ChildClass2();
$myObject1->childFunction1();
$myObject2->childFunction2();
```

I feel it  is like this

Comment: Yes, I know that. But I have property in parent class and I will call parent class in a loop. I try it that not working for me. When I call $myObject1 and set the parent property in the $myObject2 this property is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution alone.

```
class ParentClass{

      public function childFunctions($className,$functionName){
           $c = ucfirst($className);
           $$className = neew $c();
           return $$className->$finctionName(); // or echo
      }

}

class ChildClass1 extends ParentClass{

      public function childFunction1(){

      }

}

class ChildClass2 extends ParentClass{

      public function childFunction2(){

      }

}
$myObject = new ParentClass();
$myObject->childFunctions("ChildClass1", "childFunction1");
$myObject->childFunctions("ChildClass2", "childFunction2");
```

That work for my problem. Maybe someone has the same problem.

Thank you anyway.